# httpclient get error when using proxy to visit home page

Tags: java, proxy, httpclient

Recently I found httpclient has 2 different errors to visit 2 home pages, but everything works fine without proxy.

When visit http://www.baidu.com, I get:

> org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to
>   respond at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:101)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:252)
>
> ......

When visit http://www.hao123.com, I get

> http 400 error

While add / to the end of url, it will be all right again. Why?

I use httpclient 4.1.2, and the invoke code is:

```
httpclient.getParams().setBooleanParameter(ClientPNames.HANDLE_AUTHENTICATION, true);
CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
UsernamePasswordCredentials userPass = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(proxy.getUserName(), proxy.getPassword()); 
credsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT), userPass);  
((DefaultHttpClient) httpclient).setCredentialsProvider(credsProvider);
```

Comment: What kind of proxy are you using?

Comment: I have added the invoke code, and the httpclient version is 4.1.2